# Interchange of differentiation and summation

Tags: self-learning

[image]I came across an example about interchange of differentiation and summation. Can anyone show me how to prove the equation in the picture? Thank you!

Comment: Just differentiation: $-\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}(1-\theta)^x=x(1-\theta)^{x-1}$

Comment: There is no prob!em with finite sums---convergence is not an issue

Answer (score 0):

You **do not** interchange differentiation and summation. Obviuosly $\sum_{x=0}^n \theta x (1 - \theta)^{x-1} = \theta \sum_{x=0}^n x (1 - \theta)^{x-1}$. In the second step you use that $x (1 - \theta)^{x-1} = -\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} (1 - \theta)^x$ for each summand.